# Footnote's parentheses

Tags: footnotes

I try to customize footnote symbol in my document.

My goal (parentheses as big as letter 'T', number in same height as letter 'T'):

[image]

Current:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
\begin{document}
    Note\footnote{Tylko}
\end{document}
```

I've tried to change `latex.ltx` file, but without success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want that layout only in the call of the footnote, on the footnote itself, or both?

Comment: Hello :). Both of them.

Comment: An alternative method was asking me during the laboratory. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can update `\@makefnmark`, which updates the way the `f`oot`n`ote `mark` is set within the text as well as in the footnote:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{(\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark})}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Note\footnote{Footnote}

\end{document}
```

The original definition didn't have the surrounding `(`...`)`.

Comment: By one second :-)

Comment: It solved problem with parantheses, but number is still a little bit above letter 'F'ootnote

Comment: @TomaszGóral: Try [this definition](https://pastebin.com/2ff3Nish).

Answer (score 0):

If you used the AMS classes, you could rewrite the corresponding code as follows:

```
\makeatother
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \leavevmode
    (\raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\@thefnmark})%
}

\def\@makefntext{\noindent\@makefnmark\kern .5em}
\makeatother
```